# I can't seem to find anything I can change into a method in this code (Or, I dont really understand method that much). Can anyone help me?

Tags: java, methods

So, the instruction is to change the part that is changeable into a method, to be changed into a method. I can't find any.

This is the line of code

```
class Flu23 {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    final int REGION_SIZE = 20;

    int n,i,j;
    int n_in_region[][] = new int[REGION_SIZE][REGION_SIZE];

    for( i = 0; i < REGION_SIZE; i++ ) {
      for( j = 0; j < REGION_SIZE; j++ ) {
        n_in_region[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }

    for( n = 0; n < 1000; n++ ){
      for( i = 0; i < REGION_SIZE; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j < REGION_SIZE; j++ ) {
          n_in_region[i][j] = one_percent_increase(n_in_region[i][j]);
          if( i > 0 ) {
            n_in_region[i][j] +=
              one_percent_increase(n_in_region[i-1][j])
                - n_in_region[i-1][j];
          }
          if( i < REGION_SIZE-1 ) {
            n_in_region[i][j] +=
              one_percent_increase(n_in_region[i+1][j])
                - n_in_region[i+1][j];
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.print("day " + n + ":\n");
      for( i = 0; i < REGION_SIZE; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j < REGION_SIZE; j++ ) {
          System.out.printf("%3d ",n_in_region[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
      }
    }

    return;
  }

  static int one_percent_increase(int num) {
    int r;

    r = num;
    r *= 1.01;
    if( r < 100 && (int)(Math.random() * 100) < 1 ) {
      r += 1;
    }
    return r;
  }
}
```

I tried something but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

I tried this

```
    class Flu23 {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    final int REGION_SIZE = 20;

    int n,i,j;
    int n_in_region[][] = new int[REGION_SIZE][REGION_SIZE];

    for( i = 0; i < REGION_SIZE; i++ ) {
      for( j = 0; j < REGION_SIZE; j++ ) {
        n_in_region[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }

    for( n = 0; n < 1000; n++ ){
      for( i = 0; i < REGION_SIZE; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j < REGION_SIZE; j++ ) {
          n_in_region[i][j] = one_percent_increase(n_in_region[i][j]);
          if( i > 0 ) {
            n_in_region[i][j] +=
              one_percent_increase(n_in_region[i-1][j])
                - n_in_region[i-1][j];
          }
          if( i < REGION_SIZE-1 ) {
            n_in_region[i][j] +=
              one_percent_increase(n_in_region[i+1][j])
                - n_in_region[i+1][j];
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.print("day " + n + ":\n");
      for( i = 0; i < REGION_SIZE; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j < REGION_SIZE; j++ ) {
          System.out.printf("%3d ",n_in_region[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
      }
    }

    return;
  }

  static int one_percent_increase(int num) {
    int r;

    r = num;
    r *= 1.01;
    if( r < 100 && (int)(Math.random() * 100) < 1 ) {
      r = one_percent_increase_of(r);
    }
    return r;
  }
}
```

Another question.

It seems that I haven't fully understand methods.

I'm currently studying in a Japanese university and I believe the language seems to be the biggest barrier for me to learn smoothly.

Comment: What doesn't work? Please create a clear problem statement.

Comment: There is much in this code that could be written as a method, it would be extremely helpful to know if this is working code or your code that does not work. Also, in what way does the code that does not work, not work? Finally, requests for off-site resources are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: @FailingCoder I've just edited that question and put the code I tried to edit.

Comment: *"...change the part that is changeable into a method, to be changed into a method."* What does this mean?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The first code I put above is a working code. The second one is the one I edited and this error popped up:

Flu23.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
      r = one_percent_increase_of(r);
          ^
  symbol:   method one_percent_increase_of(int)
  location: class Flu23
1 error

Sorry about the off-site resources.

It would be really helpful if you could show me one or two lines where it is possible to change into method. Thanks.

Comment: @FailingCoder there are lines of this code that is changeable into a method. I got instruction to find those lines, and change it into a method.

Comment: You want to create a method instead of repeating code?

Comment: Helpful feedback: the downvotes are probably for the title. Title should be a succinct description of the problem, and refrain from any kind of begging or pleading. Everyone here is a volunteer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change one, follow Java naming conventions; `one_percent_increase` should be `onePercentIncrease` and it is difficult to reason about the current implementation. I would do

```
static int onePercentIncrease(int num) {
    int r = (int) (num * 1.01);
    if (r < 100 && (int) (Math.random() * 100) < 1) {
        r += 1;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Change two, extract a method to operate on "regions" by passing the entire `int[][]` and the indices `i` and `j`. Like,

```
static void calculateRegion(int[][] regions, int i, int j) {
    regions[i][j] = onePercentIncrease(regions[i][j]);
    if (i > 0) {
        regions[i][j] += onePercentIncrease(regions[i - 1][j]) - regions[i - 1][j];
    }
    if (i + 1 < regions.length) {
        regions[i][j] += onePercentIncrease(regions[i + 1][j]) - regions[i + 1][j];
    }
}
```

Change three, extract a method to print a single "day" like

```
static void printDay(int[][] regions, int n) {
    System.out.printf("day %d:%n", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < regions[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d ", regions[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Finally, change the `main` method to invoke those two new methods (and there is no need to fill your array with zero. Zero is the default initial value for the contents of an `int[]`).

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    final int REGION_SIZE = 20;

    int[][] regions = new int[REGION_SIZE][REGION_SIZE];

    for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < REGION_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < REGION_SIZE; j++) {
                calculateRegion(regions, i, j);
            }
        }
        printDay(regions, n);
    }
}
```